# How to speed up the display of a slider on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I create a website that contains many sliders using revolution slider on wordpress. The problem that when I access to my website, the display of the sliders is very slow. How can I fix them to will be displayed in the same time as the website?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information. It  could  be  your  slider,  it could be your images..... First thing i would do is compress you images. Do you need the sliders executing on page load,  if not turn them off and  use directional arrows. If that doesn't work run a Javascript minimmisation test, and if needs be find a plugin with GREAT reviews and minimise your site. Be sure to back up your site first though. Sliders will slow down your website bottom line. After you do all that run a speed test on your website and make sure its below 3.3 secs if you want  to  be found in search engines.